# Python requests module not passing params in session

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using am attempting to do a bulk download of a series of PDFs from a site that requires login authentication. I am able to successfully log in, however, when I attempt a GET request for *'/transcripts/transcript.pdf?user_id=3007'* but, the request returns the content for *'/transcripts/transcript.pdf'*.

Does anyone have any idea why the URL param is not sending? Or why it would be rerouted?

**I have tried passing the parameter 'user_id' as data, params, and hardcoded in the URL.**

#### I have removed the actual domain from the strings below just for privacy

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    login = s.get('<domain>/login/canvas')
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print(login.text)
    login_html = lxml.html.fromstring(login.text)
    hidden_inputs = login_html.xpath(r'//form//input[@type="hidden"]')
    form = {x.attrib["name"]: x.attrib["value"] for x in hidden_inputs}
    print("form: ",form)
    form['pseudonym_session[unique_id]']= username 
    form['pseudonym_session[password]']= password
    response = s.post('<domain>/login/canvas',data=form)
    print(response.url, response.status_code) # gets <domain>?login_success=1 200


    # An authorised request.
    data = { 'user_id':'3007'}
    r = s.get('<domain>/transcripts/transcript.pdf?user_id=3007', data=data)
    print(r.url) # gets <domain>/transcripts/transcript.pdf
    print(r.status_code) # gets 200
    with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

GET response returns */transcripts/transcript.pdf* and not */transcripts/transcript.pdf?user_id=3007*

Comment: Well, if you're properly supplying the parameter and it's not changing the contents then `<domain>/transcripts/transcript.pdf` isn't processing the `user_id` parameter in a way that affects the contents. I'm not sure that you can but looking at the source code for that endpoint might get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking through the '.history' of the request I found a series of 302 redirects. 
The first was to *'/login?force_login=0&target_uri=%2Ftranscripts%2Ftranscript.pdf'* 
In a desperate attempt, I tried: 
 *s.get('/login?force_login=0&target_uri=%2Ftranscripts%2Ftranscript.pdf%3Fuser_id%3D3007')* and this still rerouted me a few times but ultimately got me the file I wanted!

If anyone has a more elegant solution to this or any resources that I can read I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you are trying to use canvas. I'm pretty sure in canvas, you can bulk download all test attachments.

If that's not the case, There are a few things to try:

1. after logging in, try typing the url with user_id into a browser. Does that take you directly to the PDF file or links to one?
2. if so, look at the url, it may simply not display the parameters; some websites do this, don't worry about it

If not, GET may not be enough; perhaps the site uses javascript, etc.